# Automatically generating a CRUD webui

Tags: c#, .net, web, asp.net-web-api, crud

I'd like to generate a web editor for several tables in an internal database. There is no need for security.

Is there a C# library that can do this? In python I would probably use Django Admin pages or web2py. However I'd really prefer a .NET option in this case

Comment: Entity framework and reflection?

Comment: Why not use SQL management studio or similar? Most SQL editors allows you to edit rows through a grid editor

Comment: "_Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam._"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use scaffolding in ASP.Net MVC to generate the web views and have Entity framework to generate the ORM (data access) layer for you.  I am not sure if there is one library which does that for you. Hope this helps.